# Understanding correct way of using Linq to SQL in windows applications

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, windows

I am wondering what is the correct and the most optimized way of using `linq-to-sql` in a windows application.
simply suppose we have an `Order` table in database and accordingly an `Order` class in our `Datacontext`, we also have a `Form` to show `Order List` and another to show the `OrderDetails`.
The target is open each Order, change details and Save to database.

`OrderListForm.cs`

```
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext ();
    public OrderListForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        OrderBindingSource.DataSource = db.Orders;
    }
    private void OrderGridView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OrderBindingSource.Current == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Order cur = OrderBindingSource.Current as Order;
        OrderDetailForm = new OrderDetailForm (cur);
        f.ShowDialog();
        if (f.DialogResult==DialogResult.OK)
        {
           db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
    OrderDetailForm.cs


    public OrderDetailForm(Order O)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        OrderDetailBindingSource.DataSource = O;
    }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```

that was one senario, another is:

```
    `OrderListForm.cs`

MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext ();
    public OrderListForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        OrderBindingSource.DataSource = db.Orders;
    }
    private void OrderGridView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OrderBindingSource.Current == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Order cur = OrderBindingSource.Current as Order;
        OrderDetailForm = new OrderDetailForm (cur);
        f.ShowDialog();
        if (f.DialogResult==DialogResult.OK)
        {
           db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
    OrderDetailForm.cs

    MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
    Order thisOrder;
    public OrderDetailForm(Order O)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        thisOrder = db.Orders.FirstOrDefault(e=> e.ID== O.ID);
        OrderDetailBindingSource.DataSource = thisOrder ;
    }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```

the last senario:

```
            `OrderListForm.cs`

MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext ();
    public OrderListForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        OrderBindingSource.DataSource = db.Orders;
    }
    private void OrderGridView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OrderBindingSource.Current == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Order cur = OrderBindingSource.Current as Order;
        OrderDetailForm = new OrderDetailForm (cur);
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
    OrderDetailForm.cs

    MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
    Order thisOrder;
    public OrderDetailForm(Order O)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        thisOrder = db.Orders.FirstOrDefault(e=> e.ID== O.ID);
        OrderDetailBindingSource.DataSource = thisOrder ;
    }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

which one is better for an LAN-based application with many users. or is there any better suggestion.

**UPDATE:**
to be clear, there is two way that I can use:
1-passing the object to the details form:

```
    Order MyOrder = OrderBindingSource.Curent as Order;
    OrderDetailForm f = new OrderDetailForm(MyOrder);
    f.ShowDialog();
    if(f.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
      db.Submitchanges();
    else
    {
      db = new MyDataContext();  //discard changes
      OrderBindingSource.DataSource = db.Orders;  //discard changes
    }
```

2-passing the `ID` of object to the details form and retrieve it from a new instance of `Datacontext`in the `detailsform`:

```
    Order MyOrder = OrderBindingSource.Curent as Order;
    OrderDetailForm f = new OrderDetailForm(MyOrder.ID);
    f.ShowDialog();
    if(f.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       db = new MyDataContext(); //refresh to show the Updated Data
       OrderBindingSource.DataSource = db.Orders;  //refresh to show the Updated Data
    }
in detailsform:

    MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
    public OrderDetailForm(int OrderID)
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       OrderDetailBindingSource.DataSource = db.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o=> o.ID == ID);
    }

    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       db.SubmitChanges();
       DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```

Which way should I use?

Comment: You should prefer Entity Framework over LINQ to SQL, for many reasons.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I think *Linq* to *Sql* is okay depending on the project, *Entity Framework* is a pretty heavy *Object Relational Mapper* and has a steep learning curve.

Comment: I forget to say that, this project was started when entity framework not presented yet. I can't change the whole project code.